# QEMU how to ping host network?

Tags: linux, networking, qemu

I'm trying to ping from guest to my host network without success.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian_squeeze_amd64_standard.qcow2 -netdev user,id=user.0 -device e1000,netdev=user.0
```

I try to ping a random machine:

```
$ ping 10.0.2.21
Destination Host Unreachable
```

In the guest I'm only able to ping the host 10.0.2.2 (DHCP server).

Comment: Attach it to a tap device and attach the tap device & your network device to the bridge

Answer (score 13, accepted):

QEMU supports ICMP on the SLIRP backend. It is necessary to allow  so called ping socket (PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, PROT_ICMP) for users in kernel.

It is simple

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ping_group_range='0 2147483647'
```

See also http://lwn.net/Articles/422330/

Answer (score 8):

From QEMU wiki, QEMU doesn't support ICMP on the SLIRP backend.

> **User Networking (SLIRP)**
>
> This is the default networking backend and generally is the easiest to use. It does not require root / Administrator privileges. It has the following limitations:
>
> - there is a lot of overhead so the performance is poor
> - ICMP traffic does not work (so you cannot use ping within a guest)
> - the guest is not directly accessible from the host or the external network

For ICMP work you'll need use TAP, VDE or Socket.

More information:
[QEMU Wiki - Networking](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking) and alo the [Wikibooks QEMU networking section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking)

Recommended also: [advanced guide for dealing with VLANs](http://people.gnome.org/~markmc/qemu-networking.html)

Comment: There's a good overview on the networking options here as well: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking, and also an [advanced guide for dealing with VLANs](http://people.gnome.org/~markmc/qemu-networking.html)

Comment: @slm Ty. added your links in answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest and more effective way I found out for me was [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20170222115348/http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/bridge-wireless-cards/).

In summary, on the host:

```
tunctl -u <username>

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlan0/proxy_arp
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tap0/proxy_arp

ip link set tap0 up
route add -host 192.168.0.20 dev tap0   <-- to be changed by you.
```

and for the guest, just run it with:

```
kvm -hda ~/fedora.qcow2 -net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no -usb
```

or

```
qemu -hda ~/fedora.qcow2 -net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no -usb
```

You just have to configure a `tap` device, owned by your user, enable `arp proxying` and configure a `route` between your host and guest.

The author (and myself) used that to deal with the problem of bridging to a `wlan0` device, which is not supported by the Linux kernel.
But it works as well with a wired connection.  In the `arp` configuration, just change `wlan0` to `eth0`.

The guest IP address must be set by you, as `DHCP` doesn't work.

And you can already ping your host.

Answer (score 0):

I have just achieved this by directly combining the following two answers of mine:

- first, learn how to network form guest to host with other tools such as `wget`, which as easier to get working, as shown at: https://serverfault.com/questions/769874/how-to-forward-a-port-from-guest-to-host-in-qemu-kvm/951835#951835
- then, `ping` in particular is a bit harder to get working than TCP IP tools like `wget` as mentioned by others, but I also managed as shown at: [How to ping from the QEMU guest to an external URL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473448/how-to-ping-from-the-qemu-guest-to-an-external-url)

Combining those, I found the "host IP" with `ip route` and then did:

```
ping 10.0.2.2
```

and it worked.

Tested with [this QEMU + Buildroot setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/fd6062a38ce6d6a49772666a813fb9d7ccd10dac#qemu-buildroot-setup-getting-started) on an Ubuntu 19.04 host.